# ListItem.Attributes.Add not working

Tags: asp.net, custom-attributes, listitem

I am trying to add a custom attribute to list item but it is not adding it

My code is this

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(teamMemberGroup.Name, teamMemberGroup.ID);
item.Attributes.Add("teammembergroup", "true");

ddlTeamGroups.Items.Add(item);
ddlTeamGroups1.Items.Add(item);
```

It is only adding option text and value in the Html but no attributes!
My dropdown is inside an update panel but I don't think update panel is making something wrong as I am not looking for postback but it is only about the very first page load loading

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you add using

```
item.Attributes.Add("teammembergroup", "true");
```

will be added to the listitem only for client side it doesn't maintain its Attribute collection for the server side.
If you want to have a look at the added attribute you can go to "view source" of your page & can see the added attribute there in to your rendered drop down list control.

Comment: Actually I am checking the attribute in that way only, I am checking attribute in Firebug but it is not there

Comment: Are you performing any postback after adding those attributes ?
If yes then those attributes should be added again after that or else they will be lost.

Comment: Hey! Thanks Man, I am performing a postback and I think that would be the most probable reason

Comment: Your answer was saying something different, actually its your comment that took my attention to the actual issue, I have marked your comment as great comment. Thanks!