# Can not get value of checked items in checkboxlist via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkboxlist

in my application I have a checkbox list. Listed below is the html for the checkbox list, as well as the vb code that bind it on load of the page it is located on.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList Runat="server" id="chklistTeams" RepeatColumns="7" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        CellPadding="4" Font-Size="7pt"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Below is the VB to bind the checkboxlist

```
myCmd.CommandText = "Select id, title from teams"
Dim DS As SqlDataReader
DS = myCmd.ExecuteReader
chklistTeams.DataValueField = "id"
chklistTeams.DataTextField = "title"
chklistTeams.DataSource = DS
chklistTeams.DataBind()
DS.Close()
```

When a save button is hit a javascript function is called. Here is the part of the function that is called that should get us the value of the items.

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('chklistTeams');
var checkBoxList = checkList.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checkBoxSelectedItems = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxList.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxList[i].checked) {
        checkBoxSelectedItems.push(checkBoxList[i].value);
        alert('checked - checkBoxList[i]: ' + checkBoxList[i].value)
    }
}
```

All the values getting stored to the array (tested with the alert) - are coming back with the value "on" - so I then checked the html of the checkboxes in this list, here was the result for one of the checkboxes

```
<input name="chklistTeams:21" id="chklistTeams_21" type="checkbox" value="on"/>
```

I am sure the values are being binded correctly to the list - because in the old way of getting their values, you get the correct integer value for the item - listed below is that VB code that used to handle this (and returned a string of integers, depending on how many boxes were checked - did not return a list of the value "on"). I need to be able to get this via javascript for another modification we are making on this page where we must now save using PageMethods and can't use this on the back end with a public shared function

VB code that will get the right values of checked items in checkboxlist

```
    For Each li In chklistTeams.Items
        If li.Selected = True Then
            strTeamList = strTeamList & li.Value & ","
            bolTeamSelected = True
        End If
    Next
    If bolTeamSelected = True Then
        strTeamList = strTeamList.Substring(0, strTeamList.Length - 1)
    End If
```

Can anyone see why the javascript way to get the values is giving me "on" instead of the integer value like the VB way does? Thanks again for your help. Again - this must be done in JS - can't use the VB code behind way due to the function being public and shared. Thanks.

Comment: could it be that the data bound to the checkboxes is saved in viewstate and not as an attribute of the checkbox? I was browsing through this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx but could not find how to add client side attributes easily.

Comment: At the previous mentioned page under the title "Executing Client-Side Code in Response to User Action" it mentions TextBoxControl.Attributes("someAttribute") to add client side attributes but I don't know if you can bind data to this.

Comment: i dont think this is the case. i think there is something wrong or missing in the javascript that gets the items. I've binded 2 other dropdowns using the same methods and I am able to get their value in javascript. i think i am missing a step to get information about the specific list items. I attempted to add a value attribute when binding, but this did not do the trick and "on" is still returned.

Comment: Dropdown and checkboxlist are not the same controls. You even stated that value property wasn't there in the source. If it's not in the source then you can't get it using JavaScript

Comment: I meant that I can bind a dropdown the same way, using the databind VB side, which does correctly bind the checkboxlist values on the VB side. But I have found a work around for this issue and have already listed it as a suggestion for others. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like checkboxlist doesn't properly implement it's properties: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp value is a valid property for checkbox and you'd think they use the serverside ListItem property of Value for that. The items of both dropdown and checkboxlist are of type ListiItem and both have Text and Value property but only the Values in dropdownlist are rendered correctly. As I've answered before; you can add a property to be used client side (not named value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this, made global shared array, on load populated the array with the id values, then through javascipt i was able to get the index of the checked items - can then go to the array at that same index to get id value for later use.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

checkboxlist.items(index) is of type listitem, listitem has an attributes property that can set client side attributes

Here is the code example:
[ListItem.Attributes.Add not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977378/listitem-attributes-add-not-working)

In your case in the chklistTeams DataBound event:

```
foreach(ListItem li in chklistTeams.Items)
{
     li.Attributes.Add("JSvalue", li.Value);
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
checkBoxSelectedItems.push(checkBoxList[i].getAttribute("JSvalue"));
```

Comment: This worked for me - and to shorten the code you can do

    foreach(ListItem li in chklistTeams.Items)
    {
        li.Attributes.Add("data-id", li.Value);
    }